# Laravel form with multiple select didn't send all selected data when submit

Tags: php, forms, laravel, multi-select

I have Laravel form with many multiple select elements which has many data. for ex:

- Hotel select (600 option)
- Restaurants select (800 option)
- SPA select (200 option)
- Attractions select (150 option)
- Outlets select (500 option)
  If I select all options in all inputs, in the controller when checking the 
  request the (Outlets) item has only 200 option
  how to fix this? how to got all data sent from this form?
  is there any form data size in Laravel?

This my form code:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('hotels', __('membership::main.hotels')) }}
                                        {{ Form::select('hotels', $hotels, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'hotels[]', 'class' => 'multiselect form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('outlets', __('membership::main.outlets')) }}
                                        {{ Form::select('outlets', $outlets, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'outlets[]', 'class' => 'multiselect form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('airports', 'Airport & Lounges') }}
                                        {{ Form::select('airports', $airports, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'airports[]', 'class' => 'multiselect form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('beauty', 'Beauty & Fitness') }}
                                        {{ Form::select('beauty', $beauty, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'beauty[]', 'class' => 'multiselect2 form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('attractions', 'Activities & Attractions') }}
                                        {{ Form::select('attractions', $attractions, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'attractions[]', 'class' => 'multiselect2 form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="panel panel-white">                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::label('restaurants', 'Restaurant & Bars') }}
                                        {{ Form::select('restaurants', $restaurants, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'restaurants[]', 'class' => 'multiselect3 form-control')) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And I am using this library to handle multiselect function
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

in controller I just checking the data like this, and I not all my selection was submitted, its stop on specific limit but I don't know why?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    dd($request);
}
```

Comment: why don't you share what you have done so far??

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: i mean your db schema, model, controller, view code anything that can help others to understand your questions better

Comment: I added the code I use, please check

Answer (score -1):

Having so much options is not Ideal! However, I propose you look at your controller. Its possible that you paginate your result. Also it could be browser related. Until we see what you have done or what you seeing, we cannot give your an exact answer...only assumptions

Comment: I don't thing there is any paginate, when I dd($request) the restaurants element give 327 value, where it should be 595.
so I guess something in the request between form and controller.
but I don't know how to find it

Comment: Can you guarantee that your database has upto 595 data? What does your query look like? Show your controller